# How to retrieve a value from a dynamic variable

Tags: c#, dynamic

Good day
I'm trying to retrieve specific values from a dynamic, only I am not sure what key to query against.

[image: item in list]

As you can see in the image, I have followed previous examples and am trying to pass the values into a method that will find what I want. yet, when I try:

`var obj = GetPropValue(item[0], "i");`

I get an error saying I passed the incorrect key in.
 
What value should I be passing in?
 
I would ideally like to get the first 2 children values.

Comment: Deserialise your json to concrete classes and you will not need to use dynamic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using [`KeyValuePair`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2?view=netframework-4.7.2) in this case which is more type safe?

Try this:

```
var claimSet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject< List<KeyValuePair<string, string> >( yourStuff );

foreach( var claim in claimSet )
{
    string firstValue = claim.Key;
    string secondValue = claim.Value;
}
```